# What's the difference between amazon emr vs starcluster

Tags: amazon-web-services

What's the difference between Amazon EMR and StarCluster ? From what I read, I felt both do the same thing i.e creating and managing cluster of instances. Please correct if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EMR provides a managed map reduce cluster, starcluster manages EC2 instances and allows you to run map reduce but also other more varied parallel computing. It's less manageable (at least initially) but probably more flexible.